# Importing an Excel spreadsheet into SQL Server - trouble with data types

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have imported an Excel spreadsheet into a SQL Server 2014 database and one of the data types was miscalculated.  In Excel, the field is a date, but SQL Server changed it to nvarchar.  It's odd because there are other dates in the spreadsheet that were converted semi-correctly ("date" in Excel converted to "datetime" in SQL).  I know about turning off the "Prevent saving changes..." check mark but that doesn't help.  Plus I learned through looking at questions here on stackoverflow that it is not recommended, so I don't want to do it.  I did try it, though, and it still didn't change the data type.  For some reason, even when I try to force it to change the data type from "nvarchar" to "datetime", SQL won't do it.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why SQL would change the data type and not let me change it back?  Also, why would SQL change the "date" data type from Excel to "datetime" and not just leave it as "date"?  Thanks in advance for any responses.

Comment: What tool are you using to do this?  Be explicit about how you are doing this as there are many different ways to get Excel data into SQL Server and it is not obvious which one you are talking about here.

Comment: By default only the first 8 EXCEL rows are read to determine the datatype of each column. This can be increased, but only to a fairly small number such as 32 or 64. I have been unable to find an off-the-shelf tool that will scan deeper, including SSIS. If you need more control, it is probably faster to just write a reader manually - That's what I have always resorted to doing.

Comment: I am using the import/export wizard in SQL Server to import the sheets into the database.   I right click databases, select new database, right click and go to import data, then run through the wizard.  That's the only way I know how to get data from a spreadsheet into a database.  @Pieter, as to your response, if the rows are read it shouldn't have been a problem.  If you would have said the first eight columns, then I would say you have something, because there are a lot of columns in the sheet.  The first eight rows contain all the data types I need, so I'm not sure why that's a problem.

Comment: My boss has already set up the spreadsheets he wants in the database, so I can't build it from scratch using T-SQL; of course, there's a lot of data, so it would have been relatively difficult for me to do.  For now, importing the spreadsheets is a lot easier.